# Function outputs array 0 elements from nowhere

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, prepared-statement

The output of the function looks good but I'm getting extra `[0] => Array ( [1] => 1 )` from nowhere everytime. The id's are starting from 1 in my db table. Where is `0` appearing from?!

`Array ( [1] => Array ( [name] => Sual [parent] => 0 ) **[0] => Array ( [1] => 1 )** ...`

Here is the function

```
<?php

function treeGen($menu, $utype) {
    global $db;
    $tree = array();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("select id, parent, name FROM navigation WHERE menu=? AND user_type=?") or die($db->error);
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $menu, $utype) or die($stmt->error);
    $stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error);
    $stmt->store_result();
    $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $parent, $name);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $tree[$id] = array(
            'name' => $name, 
            'parent' => $parent
        );
        if (!array_key_exists($parent,$tree)) {
            $tree[$parent][$id] = $id;
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
   print_r($tree);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine the problem comes when you encounter a top-level row from the table (a row without a parent). When you process one of these rows, `$parent` is null and this conditional fires:

```
if (!array_key_exists($parent,$tree)) {
    $tree[$parent][$id] = $id;
}
```

Here `$parent` is null, which is interpreted as 0, which isn't a key that exists in `$parent` (at least, not the first time you encounter a row like this), so this results in `$tree[0]` being created. In your case, the first row where `parent` is null is the row with `id = 1`, hence `$tree[0]` is `array(1 => 1)`.

Change the above conditional to the following:

```
if (!array_key_exists($parent,$tree) and !is_null($parent)) {
```

or if your DB wrapper does not use the PHP `null` type to represent SQL `NULL` values, use something like this:

```
if (!array_key_exists($parent,$tree) and $parent != 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

something is going wrong in

```
if (!array_key_exists($parent,$tree)) {
        $tree[$parent][$id] = $id;
```

i think. try commenting this code and then print the array $tree